# How do I make an ASP.NET C# email app for user's to send feedback from my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm new to ASP.NET C# and I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a long time. I found a video on Youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Baw6O3ME8Go - that shows how to make a simple email app in ASP.NET C#. However, when I run the script, I keep getting different errors. This is what my code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace my_site
{
    public partial class contact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(txtTo.Text, txtFrom.Text, txtSubject.Text, txtBody.Text);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("jameshollan79@gmail.com", "************");
                client.EnableSsl = false;
                client.Send(message);
                status.Text = "Thanks for the feedback!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                status.Text = ex.StackTrace;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One error message showed that it was on line 22 , which is just "`{`" after the `try`. Another error said that it was line 33 which is "`status.Text = ex.StackTrace;`". Another error that it comes up with says that it is line 28 that says "`client.Send(message);`".

For that last one, the stacktrace said

> "at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
>
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
>
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>
> at my_site.contact.send_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_site\my_site\contact.aspx.cs:line 28"

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do it?

If it helps, I do have a bit of experience in Classic ASP.

Comment: Also, I think you are not posting the full exception messages, please provide it, as this is often the key information to narrow down the problem.

Comment: `client.Send(message)` is probably the correct line. But start the web page from Visual Studio using the built-in web server. That will give you debug mode, where it Visual Studio will show you the exact place where the exception is thrown, and let you set a break point ahead of that place and walk through the code to see exactly what happens. That said, Gmail requires SSL/TLS, so I know you'll have to fix that if nothing else.

Comment: @Pac0 Line 22 is just that opening curly bracket under the word "try".

Answer (score 2):

You have to do following two changes to make it work out:

1. Enable the SSL
   You have to make the EnableSSL property to true as you are working with gmail

   ```
   client.EnableSsl = true;
   ```
2. Google Account Setting

   Go to your Google Account setting of your email id "jameshollan79@gmail.com"
   Go to "`Sign-in & security`" option and under that find "`Allow less secure apps`" and turn it "ON". This is because gmail don't want to send any mail from non authentic sources.

Also as @JBrooks pointed out please do correction in from and to part of MailMessage it is MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the to and from in the wrong places. It is:

```
new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
```

But really it should be:

```
    new MailMessage("jameshollan79@gmail.com", 
     "jameshollan79@gmail.com",
     "Contact Page: " + txtSubject.Text, 
     txtFrom.Text + "<br />" + txtBody.Text);
```

Shouldn't give them the ability to edit "to".  And don't have your email address on the page or you will start getting a lot of spam.

Comment: I think what he wants is a email system that send email from "jameshollan79@gmail.com" to his guest, not in another way

Comment: @Jacky, I thought it was a "Contact Us" since the name of the page was "contact" and after sending status.Text is set to "Thanks for the feedback!"

Comment: Then it's meaning he's creating an email, send to himself, with "from" is guest's email, and it will become email spoofing. Maybe the video will give more idea? I don't have chance to watch that video

Comment: @JBrooks Actually it IS for a "Contact Us" page.

I gotta say I'm really out of the loop, though. I've been dabbling in website design since about the early 2000's and I've never heard the phrase "email spoofing". Is email spoofing bad?

Comment: @AndyHollan I totally understand your situation :). That's why we are trying to help you resolve issue bit by bit now. And yes email spoofing is bad.

Comment: @JBrooks lol I appreciate it. I need all the help I can get in this area. So what do I need to do to not be email spoofing?